# How can i send email by using information from nohup.out

Tags: shell, jmeter

i know that we can send simple email by using following command

```
    echo "Welcome" | name@youremail.com
```

but i want to use info present in nohup command like in my case i am using jmeter where it provides me summary of my test like how many total request are made,how many passed,how many failed etc.so i want to send email by using that output.The email should be like as following:

```
    subject:
    Msg : Test Type:
    Total Request:
    Passed :
    Failed:
    % of failed requests:
```

Could anyone help me with that.

Comment: What have you tried this far? Putting out some effort in terms of actual code others can then comment on and asking specific questions of parts of your programming efforts not working would probably produce more answers than what you currently have there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same info can be found in *jmeter.log* file, if it is not there, add the following lines to *user.properties* file (both files can be found in /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
summariser.name=summary
summariser.log=true
summariser.interval=30
```

After JMeter restart you should start seeing summariser output in the jmeter.log file

so you can send the whole jmeter.log file or use commands like [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) or [tail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) to send "interesting" part only.

Moreover, you can use JMeter's [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) to send the email right from JMeter test and attach log file and whatever you want to the email message.

See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) for more information on how to simulate sending and receiving emails via JMeter and sample configurations for this.